# Class losing data if returned from a function outside of the class

Tags: c++

I have code with the following structure:

```
void classA::function()
{
    AnotherClass *A = 0;
    ClassB B = new ClassB();

    A = B->setupData();
}

AnotherClass *classB::setupData()
{
    AnotherClass *a = new AnotherClass();
    // setup data
    return a;
}
```

at the return a part a has valid data.  Once the data returns one of the members is now invalid.

I have tried changing the function so that A is passed by reference and the behaviour is the same, in classB the data is valid and when returned it is valid apart from one member.

I have tried breaking the setup in to two separate functions like this:

```
AnotherClass *classB::setupData()
{

    AnotherClass *a = setupData2();
    return a;
}

AnotherClass *classB::setupData2()
{
    AnotherClass *b = new AnotherClass();
    // setup data
    return b;
}
```

once again the data is valid up until it is returned to the other class when one of the members is invalid.

I have set a breakpoint at the memory location of the data member that is vanishing to see whether it is getting overwritten but the breakpoints are not hit.  I thought it might be that this member was being assigned the address of a local or something but that does not seem to be it either.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: You return from functions marked `void`. That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Why the signature of your method are void() if you try to return something?

Comment: Oops good spot, have updated the example

Comment: Also changing the code to something completely different is annoying as hell to the reader. Proof-read *before* posting.

Comment: Yes, I apologize - do you have ideas on why the problem I am describing might be happening?

Comment: `ClassB B = new ClassB();` another typo?

Comment: You managed to leave out *exactly* the relevant parts - class definitions and the "setup" code, in particular the troublesome member.

Comment: Yes I had to trim the code as we are not allowed to put our code up here.  The principle pf the question though is whether anyone has even witnessed a dynamically allocated local member vanishing from a class when it is returned from a function to another class but not when it is returned to another function in the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sigh*

It turns out that the member vanishing from the object when it was returned to a function outside of its class but not when returned to a function inside its class was due to Visual Studio's intellisense getting confused somehow.  a colleague with Visual Studio 2013 (as opposed to 2012 Express) does not get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the pointers for *great good*™. And while we're at it, move as much as you can to the constructor.

```
AnotherClass classB::setupData()
{
    AnotherClass a(/* setup data */);
    return a;
}
```

Should get yourself rid of more than one problem at once.